# python-access elements from the first list only

Tags: python, list

I have this fruit.txt which contains the following:

```
name, color
apple, red
banana, yellow
avocado, green
```

I managed to read each line of data using this code:

```
f =open('fruit.txt','r')
lines = f.readlines()
for oneline in lines:
  oneline=oneline.strip()
  oneline=oneline.split(',')
  print(oneline)
```

It printed this result:

```
['name', ' color']
['apple', ' red']
['banana', ' yellow']
['avocado', ' green']
```

Since I need to assign the element from first list (name, color) as key for further task, how do I read the only the first list? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```py
firstline = f.readline()
```

instead of `f.readlines()`